# Matlab writing to file or convert to matrix

Tags: matlab, printf

I have trouble with writing this Matlab code to a csv or text file. How can this be done? I want the three lines values (x,y,z):

1. fprintf('%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n',(i-2)*5,A(j,1),0)
2. fprintf('%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n', A(j,i)+(i-2)*5,A(j,1),0)
3. fprintf('%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n', A(j,i)+(i-2)*5,A(j,1)-5,0)

to be written to a text or csv file.

Alternatively, to use `csvwrite` command, I am uncertain how to convert these results to a X by 3 matrix, so they can be written to a csvfile by the `csvwrite` command in Matlab.

Help would be much appreciated.

Matlab matrix: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P5h6lhs0O2fxFcxHabAO4hU84UqAZD1m/view?usp=sharing

```
clear all

%num = xlsread('Workbooklol.xlsx');

load('matlab_matrix.mat')

L=length(num);

num2=num(4:72,:);

L2=length(num2);
L3=length(num2(1,:));

%
for i=1:13;
    for j=1:3;
        if isnan(num2(i,j)) ~= 1;

            A(i,j)=num2(i,j);

        end     
    end    
end


for i=2:3;

    for j=1:13;

        if A(j,i) > 0


          fprintf('%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n',(i-2)*5,A(j,1),0)
          fprintf('%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n', A(j,i)+(i-2)*5,A(j,1),0)
          fprintf('%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n', A(j,i)+(i-2)*5,A(j,1)-5,0)


        end




    end

    fprintf('(command) \n')
    fprintf('line \n')

end
```

Comment: Do you want to write the output of `fprintf` to a file, or the statement itself?

Comment: I want it to to be written to a file such that it becomes: 0.00,745.00,0.00-> next line-> 4.80,745.00,0.00 -> next line -> x,y,z

Comment: Have you looked into the `dlmwrite` function? ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `fopen` a txt file to write, for example output.txt.

```
clear all

%num = xlsread('Workbooklol.xlsx');

load('matlab_matrix.mat')

L=length(num);

num2=num(4:72,:);

L2=length(num2);
L3=length(num2(1,:));

%
for i=1:13;
    for j=1:3;
        if isnan(num2(i,j)) ~= 1;

            A(i,j)=num2(i,j);

        end     
    end    
end

fileID = fopen('output.txt','w');

for i=2:3;

    for j=1:13;

        if A(j,i) > 0


          fprintf(fileID,'%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n',(i-2)*5,A(j,1),0);
          fprintf(fileID,'%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n', A(j,i)+(i-2)*5,A(j,1),0);
          fprintf(fileID,'%.2f,%.2f,%.2f \n', A(j,i)+(i-2)*5,A(j,1)-5,0);


        end




    end

    fprintf(fileID,'(command) \n');
    fprintf(fileID,'line \n');

end

fclose(fileID)
```

In the output.txt file:

```
0.00,745.00,0.00 
4.80,745.00,0.00 
4.80,740.00,0.00 
0.00,740.00,0.00 
3.00,740.00,0.00 
3.00,735.00,0.00 
(command) 
line 
5.00,747.00,0.00 
16.00,747.00,0.00 
16.00,742.00,0.00 
5.00,742.00,0.00 
18.00,742.00,0.00 
18.00,737.00,0.00 
(command) 
line
```